# Type conversion in Python

Tags: python, types

Is there a way to convert a Python object from one type to another based on the given value?

```
>>> first = 1
>>> second = '2'
>>> type(first)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(second)
<type 'str'>
```

So, I want to convert `first` to the type of any given `second` object. I am not really sure how to do this.

Comment: As pointe out below, you can do this but it won't work for any given type. Are you asking out of curiosity or is there a specific use case?

Comment: Ya i ve use case for query mongodb base on the given value. like query for "False" is different than querying boolean (false).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could call the type of one of the objects using the other object as a parameter. This doesn't necessarily work for all types, but it does work for your specific example:

```
>>> first = 1
>>> second = "2"
>>> type(first)(second)
2
>>> type(second)(first)
'1'
```

This is no different than doing `int(second)` and `str(first)`, except the types are determined dynamically instead of you specifying them manually.

Comment: awesome :) thank you so much i lost around 2 hours thinking about that.

Comment: Ya my types are dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> int('1')
1
```

Above answer is better, tho